# Copy Data Table to a Data Grid without binding them together

Tags: c#, datagridview, datatable

I have two datagrids in my application (`dataGridView1` and `dataGridView2`). I am moving selected items from `dataGridView1` into `dataGridView2`. Here is how I am currently doing this:

```
DataTable dt = new DataTable("dt");
DataTable id = new DataTable("id");
try
{
    if (dataGridView1.Rows.Count > 0)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < dataGridView1.Rows.Count - 0; i++)
        {
            if (dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[0].Value != null)
            {
                DataRow row;
                DataRow idRow;
                row = dt.NewRow();
                idRow = id.NewRow();
                idRow["id"] = dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[1].Value.ToString();
                row["id"] = dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[1].Value.ToString();
                row["Link Name"] = dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[2].Value.ToString();
                dt.Rows.Add(row);
                id.Rows.Add(idRow);
            }
        }
    dataGridView2.DataSource = dt;
}
```

However, I also need to be able to remove items from `dataGridView2`. Currently, the DataTable `dt` is bound to `dataGridView2` and I cant clear it after the items are added because it also clears the `dataGridView2`.

Basicly, my question would be, is there a way to add the contents of a data table to a data grid without using `datagrid.DataSource`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can manually add each row using the `dataGridView2.Rows.Add` function.  Also, I have typically used the `dataGridView2.Row(n).Tag` to hold the actual source of that row's data.

```
int n = dataGridView2.Rows.Add();
DataGridViewRow newRow = dataGridView2.Rows[n]; 
newRow.Cells[0].Value  = "ABC";
newRow.Cells[1].Value  = 123;
newRow.Tag = row;
```